# Javascript: constructor for nested objects

Tags: javascript

I have this object in JS:

```
var persona = { 
     nome: "",
     cognome: "",
     sesso: "",
     telefono: "",
     indirizzo: {
         via: "",
         numero: "",
         CAP: ""
         },
     nascita: {
        mese: "",
        giorno: "",
        anno: "",
        CAP: ""
        },
    codiceFiscale: function() 
       {
       // istruzioni per il calcolo
       },
    input: function(name,surname,sex,street,number,CAP1,day,month,year,CAP2)
      {
      // istruzioni
      }
 };
```

I would like to transform it in a constructor Persone(), so I can use it to declare an array, something like this:

```
  var archivio = new Array();
  archivio.push(new Persone());
```

How can I do? I am able to do it without nested objects, but here I am quite confused. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Use a constructor function instead of an object literal?

Comment: `function Persone () { this.nome = ''; this.indirizzo = { via: '' } }`

Answer (score 1):

Within your `Persone` constructor function, you'd assign nested objects to their properties on `this` (which refers to the new object) using the same kind of notation you're using now:

```
function Persone() {
    this.nome = "";
    this.cognome = "";
    this.sesso = "";
    this.telefono = "";
    this.indirizzo = {
        via: "";
        numero: "";
        CAP: ""
    };
    this.nascita = {
        mese: "";
        giorno: "";
        anno: "";
        CAP: ""
    };
    this.codiceFiscale = function() {
        // istruzioni per il calcolo
    };
    this.input = function(name, surname, sex, street, number, CAP1, day, month, year, CAP2) {
        // istruzioni
    };
}
```

Naturally, you can add parameters to `Persone` (for `nome`, etc.) if you like and use those when creating the properties on `this`.

You might consider moving the functions off to the prototype that `new Persone` will assign to new instances (unless they need to be different for different `Persone` instances), like this:

```
function Persone() {
    this.nome = "";
    this.cognome = "";
    this.sesso = "";
    this.telefono = "";
    this.indirizzo = {
        via: "";
        numero: "";
        CAP: ""
    };
    this.nascita = {
        mese: "";
        giorno: "";
        anno: "";
        CAP: ""
    };
}
Persone.prototype.codiceFiscale = function() {
    // istruzioni per il calcolo
};
Persone.prototype.input = function(name, surname, sex, street, number, CAP1, day, month, year, CAP2) {
    // istruzioni
};
```

It's also worth looking at the newish [`class` syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/class), which you can use today with transpiling (or, increasingly, without):

```
class Persone {
    constructor() {
        this.nome = "";
        this.cognome = "";
        this.sesso = "";
        this.telefono = "";
        this.indirizzo = {
            via: "";
            numero: "";
            CAP: ""
        };
        this.nascita = {
            mese: "";
            giorno: "";
            anno: "";
            CAP: ""
        };
    }

    codiceFiscale() {
        // istruzioni per il calcolo
    }

    input(name, surname, sex, street, number, CAP1, day, month, year, CAP2) {
        // istruzioni
    }
}
```

Finally, if you want to create those nested objects with constructors as well, you'd just do that and then use the constructors within `Persone`:

```
class Indirizzo {
    constructor() {
        this.via = "";
        this.numero = "";
        this.CAP = "";
    }
}

class Nascita {
    constructor() {
        this.mese = "";
        this.giorno = "";
        this.anno = "";
        this.CAP = "";
    }
}

class Persone {
    constructor() {
        this.nome = "";
        this.cognome = "";
        this.sesso = "";
        this.telefono = "";
        this.indirizzo = new Indirizzo();
        this.nascita = new Nascita();
    }

    codiceFiscale() {
        // istruzioni per il calcolo
    }

    input(name, surname, sex, street, number, CAP1, day, month, year, CAP2) {
        // istruzioni
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

ES6 (using [Classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)):

```
class Persone {
        constructor() {
            this.nome = "";
            this.cognome = "";
            this.sesso = "";
            this.telefono = "";
            this.indirizzo = {
                via: "";
                numero: "";
                CAP: ""
            };
            this.nascita = {
                mese: "";
                giorno: "";
                anno: "";
                CAP: ""
            };
        }

        codiceFiscale() {
            // istruzioni per il calcolo
        }

        input(name, surname, sex, street, number, CAP1, day, month, year, CAP2) {
            // istruzioni
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function Persona(nome, cognoma) {
  this.nome = noma;
  this.cognoma = cognoma;
}

var persona = new Persona('test', 'test2');
persona.nome // will equal test
persona.cognoma // will equal test2
```

This should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the data into the constructor function when initializing.

```js
var Persona = function(data){
  this.data = { 
     nome: data.nome,
     cognome: data.cognome,
     sesso: data.sesso,
     telefono: data.telefono,
     indirizzo: data.indirizzo,
     nascita: data.nascita
 };
}

Persona.prototype =  {
   codiceFiscale: function(){     
       //data object is accessible here as
       //this.data.nome...
   },
   input: function(name,surname,sex,street,number,CAP1,day,month,year,CAP2){
      // istruzioni
   }
}

var arr = new Array();

arr.push(new Persona({
   nome: "nome1",
   cognome: "cognome1",
   sesso: "sesso1",
   telefono: "telefono1",
   indirizzo: {},
   nascita: {}
}));

arr.push(new Persona({
   nome: "nome2",
   cognome: "cognome2",
   sesso: "sesso2",
   telefono: "telefono2",
   indirizzo: {},
   nascita: {}
}));


console.log(arr);
```